# How does the Gradle compileTestJava step work?

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I have a complicated build where the Java source files have to be preprocessed before being compiled. It's all a bit messy, but that all works. Next I wanted to get the junit tests working. I added them in `src/test/java`, but they don't compile. The `compileTestJava` task reports hundreds of package/class not found errors for classes that are part of the project.

My first thought was that the compiled classes weren't in the classpath because the output directory is odd (see previous remarks about preprocessing), so I added them explicitly:

```
  testImplementation (
    'junit:junit:4.12',
    'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2',
    fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/classes/hej")
  )
```

If I make my own configuration that extends `testCompileClasspath`:

```
configurations {
  normtest.extendsFrom(testCompileClasspath)
}
```

and print out the classpath:

```
task helloWorld() {
  doLast {
    configurations.normtest.each {
      println it
    }
  }
}
```

The classpath clearly includes the classes that `compileTestJava` reports as missing.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

I believe my error was `fileTree(dir: ...)` in the `testImplemetation` where what I wanted was `files(...)`.